# I cannot add content to Weceem through the admin screen

Tags: grails, content-management-system, weceem

I got Grails CMS (Weceem) up and running. Through the admin screen I have been able to modify existing text or add new HTML pages. However I cannot add any resources folders.

When I click on **New Content** and select **Folder** and enter a folder name, checked under **"Parent & Children"** and it said **Parent: resources(Server Directory)** so I hit save. It looks like it completes but nothing is created. I refreshed the screen, expanded the resources folder and my newly created folder did not show under **resources**

However when I go into the actual server through ssh client I can see that the folder got created under
**/root/weceem-uploads/WeceemFiles/_ROOT/resources**

But yet it does not appear on the admin screen.

Anybody know why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I had to choose **Server Directory** instead of **Folder**. I guess it was misleading because if I choose folder it also puts it under the server directory (at least according to the Parent label under the **Parent & Children** section